# On the security of OAEP

Tags: rsa, padding, oaep

I saw theorems stating that RSA-OAEP (or the similar variant OAEP+) is CCA-secure in the *random* oracle model.

I wonder about the following:

- Is RSA-OAEP (or even OAEP+) CPA-secure in the plain model? If so, what properties does the hash functions need to hold?
- Are there any lower bounds for the padding length compared to the plaintext? I remember hearing that one needs to have at least $\Theta(n)$ bits of padding to argue security.
- Are there any upper bounds for the plaintext length compared to the modulus (when using a single exponentiation)?

Comment: You can simply put dollar signs around your $\LaTeX$ to get it formatted (SE allows MathJAX on specific sites such as cryptography). Double dollar signs will center a formula and put whitespace around it. No need for all the niceties / fluff, we'll take upvotes, accepts and good responses instead :)